# File comparison script not working Python

Tags: python

I wrote a custom file comparison script based on the nature of the files I'm checking. Essentially the file is read into a dictionary and then the script tries to hash the lines to determine if the line exists in the other file.

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('test2.txt', 'r')

m1 = {}
m2 = {}
for line in f:
    m1[line] = line
for line2 in f2:
    m2[line2] = line2

for k in m1:
    try:
        l = m2[k]

    except KeyError:
        print m1[k]

f.close()
f2.close()
```

I put a trash line in one of the files and the script did not print it out. Why didn't it detect the trash line?

Comment: Include mockup input files, please, don't let us guess what you did. For example, if you added an extra trash line (instead of replacing an existing line) in test2.txt, you are not going to find it because you only look at the keys of m1.

Comment: If the trash is in the second file, you only iterate over keys generated from the first file.

Comment: @PeterWood. You're right, thanks. I just noticed that.

Comment: Your keys and values are the same. You might as well use sets, and check for intersection: `set(f) & set(f2)`.

Comment: See also [**`difflib`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#module-difflib) and [**`filecmp`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Following @PeterWood's suggestion,

```
def get_line_set(fname):
    with open(fname) as inf:
        return set(line.rstrip() for line in inf)

f1 = get_line_set("test.txt")
f2 = get_line_set("test2.txt")

only_in_f1 = f1 - f2
if only_in_f1:
    print("\nThe following lines appear in f1 but not in f2:")
    print("\n".join(sorted(only_in_f1)))

only_in_f2 = f2 - f1
if only_in_f2:
    print("\nThe following lines appear in f2 but not in f1:")
    print("\n".join(sorted(only_in_f2)))
```